# Journals with fast response?

Tags: peer-review, journals, electrical-engineering

Are there any other impact factor journals for electrical, electronics, communication engineering (or multi-disciplinary) with a very fast response like mdpi journals? I know it is not wise to ask for a fast response as it is normal for the process to take some time. However, I am in a situation where it is very important for me to get a publication in the next 1-2 months.

Comment: Google predatory journals, they usually respond very fast and target people that need to publish in such a short time. If you're at it, maybe also read about how they got that name though.

Comment: Maybe you can re-phrase your question much more generally, which would be interesting to people. How to know about journal process length?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at https://scirev.org/ , where people can submit there experience with different journals. Quite a few are missing (in my field) but a lot are there.

A nice feature is that you can look by field / subfield and have all the things summarized in a table.
If you look at [electrical engineering](https://scirev.org/discipline/BF07/electrical-engineering/) there is a surprising number of them with fast turnover and considered as "good" by the people who submitted there.

Comment: This is an interesting resource, but at least for the pure math journals (where there's not much data yet) the reviews don't seem to be representative of typical experiences.  Maybe this will get better over time though.